# VS Code - How to make brackets, parentheses, and square brackets bold

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

[image]

I love this color theme but I hate how much the curly brackets, square brackets, and parentheses are washed out.

The curly brackets I managed to leave bold.

```json
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations":
    {
        "textMateRules":
        [{
            "scope": ["punctuation"],
            "settings": {"fontStyle": "bold"}
        }]
    },

It improved a little, but the parentheses and square brackets are still very faint. I'm testing other settings, but I can't find which ones affect the parentheses and square brackets.

Any help is welcome.
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution! I opened the Command Palette `Ctrl+Shift+P` and ran the **Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes** function, and clicked on the characters that showed me the scope that takes care of customizing that character.

After discovering the scope, I simply edited the respective settings in `settings.json`:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations":
{
    "textMateRules":
    [{
        "scope": ["punctuation"],
        "settings": {"fontStyle": "bold"}
    }]
},
```